# What is the maximum text size tk.Text widget can contain in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building an application and one of its functionality will be text accumulation. Whenever a user *loads* the file, its contents will be *inserted* into `tk.Text` widget. Possible txt file sizes are ~5mb.

I wonder if I should take care of the size `tk.Text` can contain? 
Does `tk.Text` has a limit on inserted data? 
What potential issues may occur?

Comment: Try loading a 5mb file and see what happens.

Comment: Loaded 7.5mb text file, loaded in seconds and I can freely scroll it without any lag.